# Regex end of line with specific value notepad++ form csv file

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++

I have a big csv file which I need to edit in specific way:

Code:

```
56;CZ;null;;null;49,7500;15,5000;null;
57;DE;null;;null;51,0000;9,0000;null;
58;DJ;null;;null;11,5000;43,0000;null;
133176;US;GA;Brookfield;31727;31,4185;-83,3910;525;229
133177;US;PA;Daisytown;15427;40,0668;-79,9722;508;724
```

I need to add at the end of the line 'null' value if there is nothing after last ';'
So i need to obtain something like that after execute my regex

```
56;CZ;null;;null;49,7500;15,5000;null;null
57;DE;null;;null;51,0000;9,0000;null;null
58;DJ;null;;null;11,5000;43,0000;null;null
133176;US;GA;Brookfield;31727;31,4185;-83,3910;525;229
133177;US;PA;Daisytown;15427;40,0668;-79,9722;508;724
```

Do you have any ideas? I already try to use notepad++ replace function with regex

```
find what: ;\n
replace with: ;null\n
```

but i get something like this:

```
56;CZ;null;;null;49,7500;15,5000;null;
null
57;DE;null;;null;51,0000;9,0000;null;
null
58;DJ;null;;null;11,5000;43,0000;null;
null
133176;US;GA;Brookfield;31727;31,4185;-83,3910;525;229
133177;US;PA;Daisytown;15427;40,0668;-79,9722;508;724
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the followin pattern instead and replace using `;null`

```
;$
```

This is a simple pattern wich gets all Semicolon‎s located at the end of a line ($ means before an optional \n, and the end of the string)

[image: notepad++]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be the use of a **Positive Lookbehind**.

```
Find: (?<=;$)
Replace: null
```

Regular expression:

```
(?<=           look behind to see if there is:
 ;             ';'
 $             before an optional \n, and the end of the string
)              end of look-behind
```

See [`Live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/gJ0kC2)